# Getting data from multiple tables via Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables; `rate_params`, `review_form_languages`, and `review_form_translations`. And corresponding models `RateParam`, `ReviewFormLanguage` and reviewFormTranslation.

`rate_params` has columns id, info_message, order and validation.

`review_form_languages` has id and name

`review_form_translations` has id, rate_params_id, review_form_languages_id, and text.

I would like to have query that fetches all the data from `rate_params` and the text from `review_form_translations` where `review_form_languages.name` is the passed parameter.

I have a query that fetches all the data from RateParam model as below

```
 $reviewForm = RateParam::select(
        'rate_params.id',
        'rate_params.validation',
        'rate_params.info_message',
    )->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
```

How do I join to get the text from `review_form_translations` where `review_form_languages.name` is the passed parameter?

Comment: use ->join(....)

Comment: @ViperTecPro how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ,

```
 use DB; // Top of the file

 $reviewForm = DB::table('rate_params')
               ->join('review_form_translations','rate_params.id','=','review_form_translations.rate_params_id')
               ->join('review_form_languages','review_form_languages.id','=','review_form_translations.review_form_languages_id')
               ->orderBy('rate_params.order', 'asc')
               ->get()
               ->toArray();
```

Comment: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error syntax to use near 'review_form_translations.rate_para  
  ms_id `` inner join `review_form_languages` on' at line 1 (SQL: select * fr  
  om `rate_params` inner join `review_form_translations` on `rate_params`.`id  
  ` review_form_translations.rate_params_id `` inner join `review_form_langua  
  ges` on `review_form_languages`.`id` review_form_translations.review_form_l  
  anguages_id `` order by `rate_params`.`order` asc)

Comment: You can also define relationship between them in models

Comment: I updated code i forget to include '=', please try now